# Cyclic Variation of SSD free disk space: WinDirStat results

Tags: ssd, hibernate, pagefile, windirstat

When I first start my PC it says I have only have 1.1 GB free space! However when I restart it says 11.4 GB, if I then restart again it goes back to 1.1GB and so on. The actual figures are getting smaller over time but then difference is fairly constant at about 10GB. (I'm running windows7 pro SP1).

From researching the problem if seems that PageFile and Or Hiberfil may be to blame. In addition if you look at the jpeg of the WinDirStat results you can see that more of the difference can be attributed to the system files.

1.) Have I done enough to prove that Pagefile of Hiberfil are causing the problem? If not what extra work should I do?

2.) Would PageFile/Hiberfil cause the cyclical changes in free disk space I've been experiencing?

Baz

[image: showing 11.4 GB free]

The first picture shows 11.4GB free

[image: showing only 1.1GB free]

The second shows only 1.1GB free

Comment: What are the filenames of the two large files?

Comment: How much RAM is in the machine?

Comment: @ Julian I have 16GB RAM @ Steven I have been going by the summary in the top right I'm not sure how to ID the individual files?

Comment: @Bazman Click on the large file.  It will become selected.

Comment: OK seems that PageFile is cuasing the cycles it varies from 0.7GB to 12.3GB!!! HiberFil is constant at 12GB.

Comment: So seems moving Pagefile to my 2nd drive and deleting Hiberfil will resolve the issues? As it is my machine can't hibernate (I bought it overclocked and this inability to hibernate is due to the overclocking). In any case as my machine can't Hibernate it seems removing Hiberfil is a no brainer right?

Comment: I have 64 bit version of Windows and I normally have hundreds of tabs open.

Comment: However the number of tabs open doesn't change but the Pagefile size does in a very systematic manner?

Comment: I have Firefox and Chrome which I switch between, The Chrome is kept fairly empty the firefox is the one with all the tabs open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you, from a command prompt, run the following commands:

```
cd \
dir /A:SH *.sys
```

You will see the files. On my own Windows 8.1 machine, I get:

```
 Directory of C:\

2015-05-21  08:53     6,792,314,880 hiberfil.sys
2015-05-21  08:53     1,342,177,280 pagefile.sys
2015-05-21  08:53        16,777,216 swapfile.sys
               3 File(s)  8,151,269,376 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  214,779,428,864 bytes free
```

So simply run the same commands under the 2 different free space situations to get your answer.

If you can update your question with the amount of RAM you have, it might also shed some further light. However, if your drive is too small, you need to free some space. This is the disadvantage of running on an SSD.

You could turn off the hibernation feature which should remove (or allow you to remove) the hiberfil.sys That file should be around a similar size to the amount of RAM you have installed. I have 8GB of RAM for example and my file is just over 6GB.

Your pagefile is also related to RAM but differently as you are likely to see that file grow dependent on the RAM you *need* vs the RAM you *have*. Running too much with too little RAM will make it grow.

UPDATE: As you cannot hibernate due to other issues, you should disable this feature.

Moving the pagefile to another drive if you have one is an option though actually you will probably get much better performance (unless the 2nd disk is also an SSD) by moving files used less often such as images or music.

Comment: OK but what is causing the cyclicity of PageFile? Is this normal or something I should look to address?

Comment: Sorry forgot to say thanks for help so far but would like to sort out the cyclic Pagefile problem too

Comment: Cyclic page file size is not a problem, it is a feature. Your running programs NEED that memory. The best you can do is to hard cap its size by right clicking my computer, properties, advanced system settings, then under performance, advanced. Or you could put it on a HDD but that would greatly reduce the speed of your computer.

Comment: Understood just seems odd that it should cycle is such a systematic fashion. Will do some additional testing as shown above!

Answer (score 1):

A page file starts small and grows as needed.  You must be running some memory intensive application(s).

Running Firefox and Chrome with hundreds of tabs open requires a **HUGE** amount of memory.

To view memory usage:

- In Firefox, navigate to **about:memory** and click "Measure"
- In Chrome, navigate to chrome://memory.

Manually setting the page file size will reduce some overhead,

Consider adding RAM to match usage or reducing usage to match your RAM.

Comment: I suspect this is the root cause. But it's still a bit odd the difference in PageFile sizes happens on start-up before I start either browser? When I start firefox there is apparently no change in the SSD disk space being usd? I guess the Pagefile size relates to how I finished the previous session? Will do some testing to see whether not opening firefox at all means that the pagefile stays small after the next re-start.

Comment: If the pagefile does grow before Firefox has been started, check Task Manager (click "Show processes from all users") to check system memory usage (Performance tab) and Processes (tab).

Comment: Nothing obvious in TM (nice idea though). With the Hibernate gone I have a decent buffer even when Pagefile is in its enlarged form, but would be nice to pin the cyclic behaviour down exactly. For that reason I'll leave the question open a little longer.